# Linking so-file statically without being present

Tags: c++, unix, shared-libraries

I want to link a .so file in a static fashion using gcc. Problem is: The .so file is not available on the build machine.

This library is installed on the target machine. The linking itself has to be done on a Host machine (some code generation and creating the ELF afterwards) in a toolchain. For Licensing reasons, the .so file may not be part of the toolchain installation.

For Windows this problem would be easy: Every DLL also has a .lib file for static linking to the DLL, so we don't need the DLL for the linking step. Is there some comparable mechanism for unix available?

Comment: A DLL *may* have a static `.lib` file. Or it's just an export library which only tells what functions are in the DLL. As for your shared library, static libraries in POSIX environments have a `.a` ending, and if you can't copy the shared library to the host system because of licensing reasons, then you most likely can't copy the static library either for the same reasons.

Comment: Under what kind of licensing scheme were you sold a library to that you're not allowed to link?

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong: Of course I am allowed to copy the file in this directory and I can link it from there as well. The Problem is, I can't put the lib into the toolchain installation file, so whoever installs this toolchain has to make sure to put the library in some folder by himself (Which I want to avoid)

Comment: `.so` are dynamic libraries, so you need a static version of your lib as under Windows. In Unix static libraries are usually `.a` files. I'm not sure your question is very clear...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - the difference is that in Windows you can generate a lib file which is just a stub for the actual dynamic DLL and this lib handles dynamic loading of the DLL, so you can just build your app linking to the stub lib without having the corresponding DLL on your machine. Only during runtime the DLL will be required. Philipp is asking if there is a similar solution for *nix - that is, statically linkable .a files which are just stubs for dynamic .so libraries.

Comment: @JustAMartin There is dynamic linking in Unix of course, but you need at least the lib to be able for the link edition (at "compile"-time), and then you can specify at run-time here to locate the lib.